# Implicit solution to first degree ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im a bit confused. Lets take $$\begin{cases} y\, y'=-x\\ y(0)=1 \end{cases}$$
Does this equation have as solution: the whole circle $x^2+y^2=1$ or just the positive part $y(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is the only answer since y must be a differentiable function.

Comment: What about questions like: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590017/solve-y-x3y-2x2dx-x-4xy4-8y3dy-0/ Where you cant write y as an f(x) ?

Comment: I guess the solution is the function in a neighborhood of the initial condition in that relation, not all the curve. (?)

Comment: That expression is not generally a function unless you bound it to some subinterval ...